# Brontotherium Stat block Missing Damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, damage, animal-companions

As the title states, the [Brontotherium](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/animal-companions/#TOC-Brontotherium) animal companion listing is missing something from its stat block.

It states in its special abilities from 7th level advancement that it gets powerful charge (slam), but doesn't state the additional damage dealt.  When looking at the Bestiary, [Brontotherium](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/megafauna/megafauna-brontotherium-tohc/) is very different in that it has a gore attack that deals the same amount of damage as the slam attack, and lists the powerful charge as (4d8+24).

So, my question is this: does the animal companion brontotherium simply not get any bonus damage from powerful charge, or should it be the same amount as the bestiary version, since their normal attack damage (2d6) is the same albeit different attacks (slam vs gore)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HeroLab gives a 7th level Druid's Brontotherium (no Ability Score changes applied, for 22 Strength) *Powerful Charge (Slam, 4d6+9)*

There doesn't seem to be a universal 'formula' for determining correct Powerful Charge damage. Other Animal Companions range from *Powerful Charge (1d8)* to *Powerful Charge (2d8)* and include another that doesn't list any damage (Elasmotherium).

### However, this is supported by the *most common* application, which seems to be 2*(natural weapon damage dice) + 1.5*Strength.

1. Minotaur, Bleeding Horror

   - Slam 1d8
   - Powerful Charge 2d8
2. Rhinoceros

   - Gore 2d6
   - Powerful Charge 4d6
3. Triceratops

   - Gore 2d10
   - Powerful Charge 4d10

Of course there are exceptions, such as

1. Arsinoitherium

   - Slam 4d8
   - Powerful Charge 4d8